# How to apply am additional html class to all select tags rendered by simple_form

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, simple-form, jquery-chosen

I have a Rails 3.2 application with the simple_form gem (2.0.0). I want to use [Chosen](http://harvesthq.github.com/chosen/) for my select fields. Right now I need to add a `:input_html => {:class => "chzn-select"}` to all my select fields.

**Is there a way to add `chzn-select` to the default html classes of a select field rendered by simple_form?**

Answer (score 2):

I have solved this in a couple different ways.

I have added a class:

```
class CollectionSelectInput < SimpleForm::Inputs::CollectionSelectInput

  def input_html_classes
    super.push('chzn-select')
  end

end
```

This will apply a class for all my form.association select boxes.

You can also solve this by adding a custom wrapper class in simple_form initalizer or for me it was inside simple_form_bootstrap.rb

Comment: How do you enable/use this input ?

Comment: @voondo '/app/inputs/custom_select_input.rb' docs here: https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form#custom-inputs

Answer (score 0):

You could use JQuery if you don't mind it not working for non-javascript enabled browsers;

```
$("input").addClass('chzn-select');
```

http://api.jquery.com/addClass/

Comment: I am not a big fan of JavaScript touching my HTML unless it is something that only JavaScript can do.